# How to sort with priority and dates?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have the following PostgreSQL query.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE user_id=$user_id ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN (date_completed_utc='0000-00-00 00:00:00') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
```

Here is an example of what's in the table:

[image]

*date_requested_utc* is always a past date.

*date_completed_utc* is defaulted to '0000-00-00 00:00:00', but is later changed to a date newer than *date_requested_utc*.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

If *date_completed_utc* is the default, then all these rows will be above all else, but these rows are sorted by *date_requested_utc* descending.

But if *date_completed_utc* is not the default, then put these rows at the bottom and order these rows by *date_completed_utc* descending.

The resulting order by ID should be as follows:

```
26, 20, 18, 17, 15, 16, 27, 28
```

I've tried all these different CASE statements, but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: You should also provide some sample data  and make it clear to us what  exactly you want to see in the output.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I updated it. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Sample data should always be in the text format. Don't post images.Do you like if people give answer to your question as images?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I didn't mean to offend anybody, geez. You asked for what my data looks like and that's it. This is a question about ordering. I didn't think I'd need to post any of my data. What were you asking for specifically?

Comment: Hi Alec, glad you found a solution to your problem. The convention on this site is to keep Questions and Answers separate, so rather than editing the solution into the Question, [you are encouraged to post an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You can then tick that as the "accepted answer", and the question will show up as answered in other people's search results.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use double orders.

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE user_id=$user_id 
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (date_completed_utc='0000-00-00 00:00:00') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    date_requested_utc DESC
```

**EDIT**

I saw your edit question.

You don't have to use `UNION ALL` combine two query,you can query one with `CASE WHEN` expression directly.

`Order by` the number

1. `1/(EXTRACT(epoch from age(now(),date_requested_utc)) / 86400` `date_requested_utc` closer the time will get larger the number.
2. `1/(EXTRACT(epoch from age(now(),date_completed_utc::timestamp)) / 86400)::numeric` `date_completed_utc` closer the time will get larger the number.

you can try this.

```
SELECT id
SELECT id FROM table 
WHERE user_id=$user_id 
ORDER BY
    (
      CASE WHEN (date_completed_utc='0000-00-00 00:00:00') 
        THEN (EXTRACT(epoch from age(now(),'1970-01-01')) / 86400) + 1/(EXTRACT(epoch from age(now(),date_requested_utc)) / 86400)::numeric
        ELSE  1/(EXTRACT(epoch from age(now(),date_completed_utc::timestamp)) / 86400)::numeric
      END
    )::numeric 
    DESC
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5f88a/28*

Comment: This didn't work. All of the ones where date_completed_utc='0000-00-00 00:00:00' are at the top and ordered by date_requested_utc DESC, but the ones below that are not the default are ordered oldest to newest. I need it to be newest to oldest.

Comment: @Alec Could you get some sample data and expect result?

Comment: The order I get with your code is 26, 20, 18, 17, 15, 28, 27, 16. I updated the post with what my data looks like as well as what the order should be. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Alec I saw you find your solution,But I figure out another more high performance solution, you can try it :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

I changed my query to the following and it's now working fine.

```
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE user_id=$user_id AND date_completed_utc='0000-00-00 00:00:00' ORDER BY date_requested_utc DESC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE user_id=$user_id AND date_completed_utc!='0000-00-00 00:00:00' ORDER BY date_completed_utc DESC)
```